# Mutate number to 2 decimal places as numeric in R

Tags: r, dplyr, format, numbers, tidyverse

I have a very simple question that I cannot seem to solve.

How do I change the number 2 to 2.00, as a numeric in my data table with R? Every round(), format(), sprintf(), digit etc. changes the numerical 2 to 2.00 as a character. Same goes for if I wanted one decimal place by changing 2 to 2.0.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: so what is `2.00`? it is just `2` you cannot have `2.00` as a number, just the same way you can not have `003` as a number. Unless you create a new class that can do so. ie display them as `2.00` yet maintain them as numeric

Comment: 2 or 2.00, for R it is (more or less) the same. When printing the number to the screen, you can display the number in different ways, e.g. with more or less decimal places, but this doesn't change the original number. As you have noticed, to store the number in a particular presentation (e.g. as 2.00) you need to store it as character instead, as you have experienced with `format`, `sprintf` etc.

Comment: @onyambu, when you say create a new class can you elaborate? A JSON schema is validating that the numeric value for part of my file is a multiple of .01. Everytime I change the value to a character (e.g. 2.00) the numeric output of the JSON has quotation marks which is not correct, so that is why I was attempting this change at the data frame level.

Comment: @tpscp I have provided a working example in the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to write a simple class that can perform the task you desire:

```
print.my_numbers <- function(x){
  y <- sprintf(sprintf("%%.%df", attr(x, 'after')), x)
  print(y, quote = FALSE)
}

my_numbers <- function(x, after=0){
  structure(x, after = after, class = 'my_numbers')
}

d <- my_numbers(1:4, 2)
d
[1] 1.00 2.00 3.00 4.00
d^3
[1] 1.00  8.00  27.00 64.00
```

Note that to generalize the use of the class `my_numbers` you should consider defining the `format` method for this class